# Line break issues with PhpStorm - How can I fix it?

Tags: phpstorm

Right now, PhpStorm automatically breaks lines like this when I refactor my code by pressing CMD+ALT+L.

[image: Here is what I have right now, I clearly don't want this kind of styling.]

And this is what I need. How can I achieve this even after I press CMD+ALT+L?
[image]

I've been messing with settings but couldn't figure out how to do. I must change something in Settings > Editor > HTML but don't know which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

Preferences > Code Style > Right Margin (columns)

Set it to 250 or higher.

Problem solved.